# Print head from site in perl

Tags: perl, command-line, line, head

I need a perl inline script that prints the head section of an online file. For example:

```
perl -MLWP::Simple -e "print head \"http:stackoverflow.com\""
```

But this print results in one line. I need to print separate lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One more-

```
perl -MLWP::Simple -e 'print head("http://stackoverflow.com")->as_string'
```

Update, the response/output–

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=60
Connection: close
Date: Fri, 25 Feb 2011 21:49:45 GMT
Vary: *
Content-Length: 194708
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Fri, 25 Feb 2011 21:50:46 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 25 Feb 2011 21:49:46 GMT
Client-Date: Fri, 25 Feb 2011 21:49:46 GMT
Client-Peer: 64.34.119.12:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
```

Updated once more, for the sake of completeness. Generalized to take an argument–

```
perl -MLWP::Simple -e 'print head(shift||die"Give a URL\n")->as_string'

perl -MLWP::Simple -e 'print head(shift||die"Give a URL\n")->as_string' http://stackoverflow.com
```

And I love me teh Perl but this is probably a better solution for this task–

```
curl -I http://stackoverflow.com
```

Though the HEAD responses for curl v LWP differ in this case. :)

Answer (score 2):

Ooh, I like this far better. Requires >5.10.

```
perl -MLWP::Simple -E "say for head q(http://stackoverflow.com)"
text/html; charset=utf-8
196768
1298660195
1298660255
```

Comment: Can't believe it took me this long to look for an optional feature command line switch. I've been throwing 'use 5.01x' into my oneliners to use say, heh.

Answer (score 1):

The `head()` call returns a list.

That list, when printed, is printed by concatenating individual elements.

Instead, join with "\n":

```
perl -MLWP::Simple -e "print join('\n', head(\"http:stackoverflow.com\"));"
```

An alternative is to append "\n" to each element (this is better as it prints "\n" at the end as well):

```
perl -MLWP::Simple -e 'print map { "$_\n" } head "http:stackoverflow.com";'
```

Comment: In the first example, I suppose `'\n'` should be in double quotes

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the list head() returns.

```
perl -MLWP::Simple -e "print join qq(\n), head q(http://stackoverflow.com)"
text/html; charset=utf-8
196503
1298659282
1298659342
```